# Can we update a source that is not DepencyProperty or not INotifyPropertyChanged compliant

Tags: silverlight, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a business object that comes from the core of the application. That object does not inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged. It contains some property that my XAML code bind to it.
I only want to update the properties not the UI dynamically (OneWayToSource style).

By example, if I change the text of a text box, the source item does not get updated.
It is a limitation of silverlight that if the object does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged or use DepencyProperties that the source of the binding cannot be updated?

Answer (score 2):

The source property does not need to be a dependency property nor does the class that exposes it need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If you have the binding on the `TextBox` set to use the `TwoWay` mode editing the text box  should update the bound property even if it is a plain "vanila" property.  Note by default the focus has to leave the TextBox in order for the binding to update.

Answer (score 0):

If your business object has a `set` method on the property you want to update, then the value should be updated, provided the value you enter doesn't trigger an exception.

Not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` hinders just visual feedback.